# How to fetch data from an API correctly with xml2js

Tags: reactjs, xml2js

I am trying to use the JS fetch() coupled with the npm package xml2js to pull xml data from an API with react and display it with my frontend. I am able to do this with regular data but when it comes down to applying xml2js it is throwing back errors in relation to 'data' not being defined and such. The following code is what I have achieved so far:

```
fetch(URL)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
            trains: ArrayOfObjStationData.objStationData
        });
    });

// convert xml to object
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

parseString(data, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res.ArrayOfObjStationData.objStationData);
    this.setState({data: res.ArrayOfObjStationData.objStationData})
});
```

I think I am just incorrect about my formatting of the code but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `data` is only accessible in the context of the `fetch.then`s arrow function, you try to use it outside where it is not defined.

Comment: @sn42 so should I combine the two functions by fetching the data and putting it to res.text and then within the same function parse and set the state?